# Using "~" with a POSIX path in AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

How can I use the `~` in the following AppleScript?

```
info for POSIX path of "Users/[User]/Pictures"
```

The script should be universal, but if I replace `Users/[User]` with `~`, so that the script looks like that

```
info for POSIX path of "~/Pictures"
```

I'm getting an error that the directory is not available.

I'm thankful for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use the tilde (`~`) in AppleScript, which is shortcut to the current user's home folder in the shell.

There are many relative paths in AppleScript

```
path to desktop
```

is the alias specifier to the desktop folder of the current user, the equivalent to

```
alias "[startup volume]:Users:[current user]:Desktop"
```

The relative path to the pictures folder is

```
path to pictures folder
```

other paths

```
path to music folder
path to applications folder
path to home folder
```

etc.

Please look into the dictionary of Standard Additions for further paths

For some relative paths there is a parameter to specify the domain

```
path to library folder from user domain -- alias "[startup volume]:Users:[current user]:Libary"
path to library folder from local domain -- alias "[startup volume]:Library"
path to library folder from system domain -- alias "[startup volume]:System:Library"
```

---

`info for` is a very old part of Standard Additions. It's deprecated since Leopard but it's still working. The simplest form is to pass an alias specifier:

```
info for (path to pictures folder )
```

Comment: And how can I make the path when I'm having a folder on the desktop with the first code?

Comment: `alias ((path to desktop as text) & "folderName:")` the trailing colon is crucial  if you want to append a file name

Answer (score 1):

`~` is a shell thing, so it won't work in this context, but there's a much easier way anyway, using `path to`:

```
info for POSIX path of (path to pictures folder)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it this answer is truly universal, but since `~` is expanded by the bash shell, but I tried using the result of the expansion as the path and it worked.

```
info for POSIX path of (do shell script "echo ~/Pictures")
```

> {name:"Pictures", creation date:date "Wednesday, July 8, 2015 at 6:33:09 PM", modification date:date "Wednesday, February 8, 2017 at 2:11:52 PM", size:102529438, folder:true, alias:false, package folder:false, visible:true, extension hidden:false, name extension:missing value, displayed name:"Pictures", default application:alias "Macintosh HD:System:Library:CoreServices:Finder.app:", kind:"Folder", folder window:{0, 0, 0, 0}, file type:"", file creator:""}

it is the same result for me as running like so

```
info for POSIX path of (path to pictures folder)
```

For my case, expanding the `~/` it is useful because the situation of looking for a folder in `~/` which is not standard for Mac. Example

```
info for POSIX path of (do shell script "echo ~/Projects")
```

> {name:"Projects", creation date:date "Friday, June 17, 2016 at 11:08:50 AM", modification date:date "Wednesday, February 8, 2017 at 2:30:08 PM", size:130670100, folder:true, alias:false, package folder:false, visible:true, extension hidden:false, name extension:missing value, displayed name:"Projects", default application:alias "Macintosh HD:System:Library:CoreServices:Finder.app:", kind:"Folder", folder window:{0, 0, 0, 0}, file type:"", file creator:""}

But the same failed according to the previous method.

```
info for POSIX path of (path to Projects folder)
```

> **Syntax Error** 
>   Expected "," but found property.

**Updated after comment**

This worked for the "non-standard" folder in the home directory.

```
info for alias ((path to home folder as text) & "Projects:")
```

Comment: `path to Projects` is not a standard folder. There is no standard folder starting with a capital letter anyway. And `info for` doesn't require a POSIX path. This is valid, too: `info for  (path to pictures folder)`

Comment: thanks. i tried again to combine the solutions for locating the no-standard folder.

Comment: Practically it's not necessary to use the tilde in AppleScript at all

Comment: @vadian, Yes, but in NSNavLastRootDirectory the system saves the path with the tilde. It does not depend on the user. The user is forced to work with a tilde.