# Applescript - Pathing to a specific (non-desktop) folder location

Tags: file, path, applescript, applescript-studio

I am currently using this line of code:

set logFilePath to ((path to desktop as text) & "crash.log") as text

to path to the desktop. However, I want to path to another file path, such as ~/Library/App Support/CrManager/logs

I tried doing:

set logFilePath to ((path to ~/Library/App Support/CrManager/logs as text) & "crash.log") as text

but it did not work.
I also tried:

tell application "Finder"
set logFilePath to (folder "saves" of ~/Library/App Support/CrManager/logs as text) & ¬
"crash.log" as alias
end tell

but that failed, too.

Comment: System Events has an `application support folder` property (see ["Unable to find the application support folder for a specified application inside an Apple Script"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71500490/unable-to-find-the-application-support-folder-for-a-specified-application-inside)). You could also use `path to library folder from user domain` (see ['Using "~" with a POSIX path in AppleScript'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31118302/using-with-a-posix-path-in-applescript)).

Comment: `path to (folder)` works with a limited set of folder constants, of which *desktop* is one. You can see a list in the dictionary for Standard Additions or in the [Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW19) under *Commands*. By the way, the second 'as text' in your opening line is redundant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expand a POSIX path with prefix "~" (using AppleScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778426/expand-a-posix-path-with-prefix-using-applescript)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help.

```
set appSupportFolder to ((path to library folder from user domain as text) ¬
    & "Application Support:")
set crManagerLogsFolder to "CrManager:Logs:"

try
    -- checks if ~/Library/Application Support/CrManager/logs exists
    alias ((appSupportFolder & crManagerLogsFolder) as text)
on error
    -- creates ~/Library/Application Support/CrManager/logs folder if it doesnt exist
    do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of POSIX path of ¬
        (appSupportFolder & crManagerLogsFolder)
    -- creates an empty crash.log file
    do shell script "touch " & quoted form of POSIX path of ¬
        (appSupportFolder & crManagerLogsFolder) & "/crash.log"
end try

-- use whichever is convenient for you
set logFilePathAsAlias to (appSupportFolder & crManagerLogsFolder) & "crash.log" as alias
set logFilePathAsPosixPath to POSIX path of ((appSupportFolder & crManagerLogsFolder) & "crash.log")
```